# Write to Log file in Flex 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

Is there any way to write to a text file in Flex 4.6? Its a desktop app for AIR. I would like to write the data from several arrays, as well as the time and date.

Comment: Did you try to [google it](http://www.google.be/search?q=air+write+file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threw a simple logger together for this test project:
http://www.shaunhusain.com/DrawTextRandomly/srcview/
it's in src/util/Logger.as

As is it marks the first time a log entry is made then counts the time from then till all other log entries and outputs it along with the logged string, it also outputs the time difference from the last log entry so you can get some idea of how long it takes for a function/algorithm/operation to complete.  Feel free to grab this, albeit just a test snippet I should probably post a license on my code, I'll update the src folders with a license.txt with MIT License http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.html

You can re-purpose this class and have it write using a FileStream/File object in Flex.  File itself is basically a handle to a particular file, FileStream will allow you to call writeUTFBytes(string) to write data to a file.

Code would be something like this:

```
var fs:FileStream = new FileStream();
fs.open(new File("logfile.txt"),FileMode.WRITE);
fs.writeUTFBytes("Some output");
fs.close();
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/FileStream.html

Answer (score 2):

The [as3corelib](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib) has a [FileTarget](https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib/blob/master/src/com/adobe/air/logging/FileTarget.as) class that can be used with the Flex Logging API.

This [documentation page](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f0f.html) explains how to use the logging API.